# Emailing back at professor after he forwarded my email?

Tags: research-process, graduate-school, email

So I emailed a professor regarding graduate research assistantship and he replied by saying if it is ok for him to forward my email to his graduate student. I said yes and its been a week so I'm trying to get back to him but I'm not sure how to really phrase this email. What would be a good way to phrase a follow up email to the professor?

Comment: Key question: where in the world is this professor? In the US/UK this would be very different to say Germany.

Comment: He's in the US.

Comment: Could you clarify if you are waiting for the professor to reply to you, or if you are waiting for the graduate student to reply to you?

Comment: "Hi Steve, just following up on our chat regarding the research assistantship. I haven't heard back from your graduate student yet. Would you mind providing me with his/hers email address so that I can follow up directly?

Thanks, Mark"

Comment: I would also mention that one week is a pretty short time in academia, and professors have numerous things to deal with, that are more important than a research assistantship. You might want to consider waiting for another week or so.

Comment: Would the following work: Dear Professor x, I am hoping to follow up on my previous email to see if there has been any other response from your graduate student?

Comment: "Dear Professor X, I would like to follow up on my previous email to see if there has been any other response from your graduate student." That should work, but it's up to you when you send it.